# Assign quickly a prefix in variable names into Matrix with Sympy - Example with Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, matrix, sympy, symbolic-math

With Matlab, I can easily give the prefix of symbolic matrix elements :

For example, like this :

```
Mat4x4_SYM = sym('sp_', [4,4]);
tril(Mat2x2_SYM.') + triu(Mat2x2_SYM,1)
```

which gives :

```
Mat4x4_SYM =
    
[ sp_1_1, sp_1_2, sp_1_3, sp_1_4]
[ sp_1_2, sp_2_2, sp_2_3, sp_2_4]
[ sp_1_3, sp_2_3, sp_3_3, sp_3_4]
[ sp_1_4, sp_2_4, sp_3_4, sp_4_4]
```

How to find a way to do the same with Python Sympy ?

I tried with :

```
from sympy import symbols, Matrix

def f(i, j):
  if i == 0 and j == 0:
   return 'sp_1_1'
elif i == 0 and j == 1:                  
   return 'sp_1_2'
elif i == 1 and j == 0:                                                                                            
   return 'sp_1_2'
...


Mat4x4_SYM = Matrix(4, 4, lambda i,j: f(i,j))
```

As you can see, I want to force symmetry for this matrix in the symbolic variable names.

Is there anyone who has already met the same kind of issue to define easily like in Matlab the prefix for symbolic variable names ?

and if yes, is there a quick way to perform this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a list comprehension and f-strings:

```
In [9]: Matrix([[Symbol(f'sp_{min(i,j)}{max(i,j)}') for i in range(1, 4+1)] for j in range(1, 4+1)])
Out[9]: 
⎡sp₁₁  sp₁₂  sp₁₃  sp₁₄⎤
⎢                      ⎥
⎢sp₁₂  sp₂₂  sp₂₃  sp₂₄⎥
⎢                      ⎥
⎢sp₁₃  sp₂₃  sp₃₃  sp₃₄⎥
⎢                      ⎥
⎣sp₁₄  sp₂₄  sp₃₄  sp₄₄⎦
```

Comment: Thanks, fast and efficient !